# Finding non matching values of multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
v1      v2      v3      x
v4      v5      v6      y
v4      v5      v6      z
v7      v8      v9      w
v13     v14     v15     u
```

**Table 2**

```
col1    col2    col3    col5
v1      v2      v3      a
v1      v2      v3      b
v4      v5      v6      c
v10     v11     v12     d
v13     v14     v15     e
```

I want to check if the values in those tables for `col1`, `col2` and `col3` are exactly same. There are other columns like `col4` which I dont want to consider. There is no primary key in either table. And also some value repeat in `col1`, `col2` and `col3`. For example in table 1, (v1, v2, v3) repeats twice for (col1, col2, col3). So, those should also repeat for same number of times in table 2 also.

- Above, only (v13, v14, v15) matches.
- (v1, v2, v3) appears twice in table 2, but once in table 1.
- (v4, v5, v6) appears twice in table 1, but once in table 2.
- (v7, v8, v9) appears only in table 1, not in table 2.
- (v10, v11, v12) appears only in table 2, not in table 1.

How can I get this done in single query?

Comment: What exactly is the output you are looking for? Can you please **[edit]** your question and add the desired output as a formatted table the way you presented the input data?

Comment: Well I am unable to imagine exact output. But anything which tells which rows in two tables dont match as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the exceptions using `full join`:

```
select coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col1) as col1,
       coalesce(t1.col2, t2.col2) as col2,
       coalesce(t1.col3, t2.col3) as col3,
       t1.cnt, t2.cnt
from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      group by col1, col2, col3
     ) t1 inner join  
     (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) as cnt
      from table2
      group by col1, col2, col3
    ) t2
    on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.col2 = t1.col2 and t2.col3 = t1.col3 
where (t2.cnt <> t1.cnt) or (t1.cnt is null) or (t2.cnt is null);
```

If you want only the ones that match on `cnt`, then an inner join is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two subqueries, grouped by columns 1, 2, 3 and with a count and then join them on the column values and the count

```
        select * 
  from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) c
          from table1
         group by col1, col2, col3) t1
  join (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) c
          from table2
         group by col1, col2, col3) t2 
    on t2.col1 = t1.col1
   and t2.col2 = t2.col2
   and t2.col3 = t3.col3
   and t2.c = t1.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all matching tuples with this query:

```
select col1, col2, col3
  from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt 
          from table1
         group by col1, col2, col3) t1
  join (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt
          from table2
         group by col1, col2, col3) t2
 using (col1, col2, col3, cnt)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a946/20/0)**:

> ```
> | col1 | col2 | col3 |
> |------|------|------|
> |  v13 |  v14 |  v15 |
> ```

You can then take the results of the above query to determine the unmatched records in the original tables individually:

```
select *
  from table1
 where (col1,col2,col3) not in (  
    select col1, col2, col3
      from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt 
              from table1
             group by col1, col2, col3) t1
      join (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt
              from table2
             group by col1, col2, col3) t2
      using (col1, col2, col3, cnt));
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a946/20/1)**:

> ```
> | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
> |------|------|------|------|
> |   v1 |   v2 |   v3 |    x |
> |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    y |
> |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    z |
> |   v7 |   v8 |   v9 |    w |
> ```

and

```
select *
  from table2
 where (col1,col2,col3) not in (  
    select col1, col2, col3
      from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt 
              from table1
             group by col1, col2, col3) t1
      join (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt
              from table2
             group by col1, col2, col3) t2
      using (col1, col2, col3, cnt));
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a946/20/2)**:

> ```
> | col1 | col2 | col3 | col5 |
> |------|------|------|------|
> |   v1 |   v2 |   v3 |    a |
> |   v1 |   v2 |   v3 |    b |
> |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    c |
> |  v10 |  v11 |  v12 |    d |
> ```

Or all together:

```
select * from (
    select 't1' src, t1.*
      from table1 t1
    union all
    select 't2' src, t1.*
      from table1 t1) u1
 where (col1,col2,col3) not in (  
    select col1, col2, col3
      from (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt 
              from table1
             group by col1, col2, col3) t1
      join (select col1, col2, col3, count(*) cnt
              from table2
             group by col1, col2, col3) t2
      using (col1, col2, col3, cnt));
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a946/20/3)**:

> ```
> | src | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
> |-----|------|------|------|------|
> |  t1 |   v1 |   v2 |   v3 |    x |
> |  t1 |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    y |
> |  t1 |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    z |
> |  t1 |   v7 |   v8 |   v9 |    w |
> |  t2 |   v1 |   v2 |   v3 |    x |
> |  t2 |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    y |
> |  t2 |   v4 |   v5 |   v6 |    z |
> |  t2 |   v7 |   v8 |   v9 |    w |
> ```

See it all in action with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a946/20)